# How do I store several lists into a textfile in python and then choice one at random?

Tags: python, list, text-files

For a project I have a **several lists** of songs and artists and I need to store the lists into a **textfile** before doing anything else.
This is my code:

```
BTS = ["Idol", "BTS"]
SWIFTY = ["Love Story", "Taylor Swift"]
RUTH = ["Lost Boy", "RuthB"]
ED = ["Perfect", "Ed Sheeran"]
ARIANA = ["No Tears Left To Cry", "Ariana Grande"]
DRAKE = ["In My Feeling", "Drake"]
RICKY = ["La Vida Loca", "Ricky Martin"]
IU = ["BBIBBI", "IU"]
MJACKSON = ["Thriller", "Michael Jackson"]
PSY = ["Gangnam Style", "PSY"]
```

How do I **store all of these into one text file?**
Then how do I randomly select one of those lists and **only output** the song or artist **not both** as the user has the guess the other *e.g Thriller is output and the user inputs Michael Jackson*

Comment: How about store it all in a dictionary instead then save as JSON, select a random key then randomly output either key or value?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using a [python dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html) to store your data, then save it as [json format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). Then you can read it back simply as follows:

```
import json
import random


songs = dict((
         ["Idol", "BTS"],
         ["Love Story", "Taylor Swift"],
         ["Lost Boy", "RuthB"],
         ["Perfect", "Ed Sheeran"],
         ["No Tears Left To Cry", "Ariana Grande"],
         ["In My Feeling", "Drake"],
         ["La Vida Loca", "Ricky Martin"],
         ["BBIBBI", "IU"],       
         ["Thriller", "Michael Jackson"],
         ["Gangnam Style", "PSY"] 
         ))


songs = json.dumps(songs)
f = open("dict.json","w")
f.write(songs)
f.close()

f = open("dict.json","r")
songs = f.read()
f.close()

songs = json.loads(songs)

choice = random.choice(list(songs.keys()))
print(choice)
print(songs[choice])
```

**Output:**

```
La Vida Loca
Ricky Martin
```